# Who is the mysterious G-man in the Half-Life series?

Tags: half-life-series

Those who played games from the Half-Life series may remember a blue-suited (maybe purple) guy who was always around somewhere as if he were observing you. At the end of each episode / sequel the main character, Gordon Freeman, had some interaction with him.

The question is simple: **Who is this guy?**

I haven't seen a clear explanation of this.

Comment: A riddle, wrapped in a mystery, inside an enigma

Comment: I'm sure Half Life 3 will answer this question, so... we'll find out in about 2020.

Comment: I hope that I don't have to wait till 2020. This is not Duke Nukem Forever. :)

Comment: Duke Nukem Forever just came out, though!

Comment: I've always wanted to punch him.... I remember getting annoyed by him. A LOT. grrr

Comment: @DoozerBlake That is an awfully optimistic release date. I'm thinking that's when we will get Episode 3.

Comment: Since Valve can only count to 2 we won't have anything with 3 in it . :D

Comment: so... [on hold] for 15 years or so?

Comment: I'm starting to think that 2020 was not a joke...

Comment: @DoozerBlake it seems like that you comment gets further from being a joke with every year. I mean 4 years have passed and we still don't have any information about HL3.

Comment: well.. already 2020 and no HL3.. that joke takes forever!

Comment: What the hell. :D

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There is not a clear explanation of this.  There's not really even a good solid HINT of this.  This is entirely deliberate on the part of the game developers - they haven't revealed SQUAT about this guy.

The Nihilanth was of the opinion he wasn't human, though: "You are man. He is not man."

There's a pretty good summary of everything we have [at the Half-Life Wikia](http://half-life.wikia.com/wiki/The_G-Man) but I doubt you'll learn anything you didn't from playing the games (except possibly locations he shows up that you missed him).

Comment: "You are man. He is not man." <-- when did this happen? I don't remember. Why do you think that Nihilanth is talking about him?

Comment: @edem - The wiki calls this out as well, I'd actually forgotten about it until I read that.  It's one of the telepathic messages you hear from the Nihilanth on Xen in the first game - they're fairly hard to understand IMO.  The assumption is simply because, well, who else would he be talking about?  It's awfully random to just be about one of the big monsters and the tense is awfully odd to be talking about himself, since he uses 'I' at another point in the game.

Answer (score 2):

In HL2: EP2, after you bring back the antlion larvae to heal Alyx, GMan starts talking with you for the last time in the series, mentioning something like "he wished he could do more than keep an eye on Gordon and Alyx, but he needed to ... FOLLOW SOME CERTAIN RULES."

This statement still bugs me since the first day I heard it, because I always thought on GMan as a "superior entity" or something, but that statement may mean he's following orders of someone... or something else. Could he be an advisor's spy? After all, he KNEW that Eli would be attacked by advisors since he whispered into Alyx's mind to tell her dad to "prepare for unforeseen consequences". And Eli DID meet GMan before.

Also, there's still another important fact. There's still a theory that when Gordon pushed that cart away in black mesa, nothing of what we know happened in real life, but inside his mind, he could be suffering of a sickness where you "dream awake".

And BEFORE we get to that chamber, all that Gordon sees are guards and scientists... but a little before reaching the chamber, he sees gman talking to a scientist. Meaning he was the ONLY DIFFERENT THING in entire black mesa, and maybe his image buried so deep into Gordon's mind that when he fell into sickness... he sometimes sees GMan in the background, or even talking to him.

Well, there's really no proof of any of these theories, but Half life canon is always fun to argue about.

Comment: The G-man makes reference to his "employers" at other points in the series (I believe during HL2's main game). He also appears to be somewhat at odds with the Vortigaunt as they intervene at the end of HL2 as well to "rescue" Freeman. Hopefully there will be a satisfying conclusion to this at some point in the future :)

Comment: This answer is *five years old*. There was no need for spoilers.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the G-man is the main cause of the massacre created in the games, because whenever he leaves or comes in game, some strange things happen.

Comment: I believe that's something to do with the Gordon-Freeman-is-needed-there-is-a-disaster thing. He is a response, not a cause.

Comment: I don't think so. For example you can see him in Lambda Complex (HL1) and nothing strange happens. (nothing more weird than what is already there)